# Submitting an image file with an ajax/json built with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

Is there anyway of submitting a file uploaded via Ajax/json/jQuery?

is there a plug in at all? if I want to submit other data its easy:

```
$.ajax(
  {
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://www.test.php",
       dataType:"json",
       data: {serial: $('[name=txtLogin]').val()},  
       success: function(data)
       { 
            ... do some stuff ...               
       }          

    });
```

But I'm guessing that file uploads are a different story. I'd like to pass information from a variety of fields such as textboxes, radio and check boxes as well as the file itself.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few plug-ins out there that can help with this.  See this [link](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/) for a decent round-up.

I've used Andrew Valums [AJAX Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) control in several projects.  It's a nice control and does the trick.  I've also uploaded additional field values (like a file name from a text box, some true/false metadata, etc.) along with the file in a single AJAX POST.

I should add that Valums' control isn't a jQuery plug-in - it's basic JavaScript.  I've used it with jQuery's $.ajax calls, though.

**UPDATE**: Actually, I recently found this [project](http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload) that looks very promising as a successor to Valums' upload plug-in.  It's jQuery focused, so I'm not sure if that's a pro or a con, but thought I'd share it.  I haven't tried it yet, but the features seem to be a good fit for you.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, you can't do that.

However, you can use the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to submit the form to a hidden iframe, which in practice makes it act the way you want.

Comment: Take a look at http://valums.com/ajax-upload/.  It will POST a file asynchronously and you can include other metadata with the POST.